# RealmSwift do something when realm count changes

Tags: swift, parent-child, parent, realm

Is there anything I can do to monitor a change in an embedded child controller variable or realm to update an Icon in the parent view controller in swift?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Realm Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) to update your parent controller when there's any change to Realm:

```
// Observe Realm Notifications
let token = realm.addNotificationBlock { notification, realm in
    viewController.updateUI()
}
```